# Javascript: replace directly with index vs Array.splice()

Tags: javascript, lodash

Today, I came across a [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27641731/is-there-a-function-in-lodash-to-replace-matched-item) to replace a matching object inside array of objects.

To do so, they are finding the index of the matching object inside array of objects using [lodash](https://lodash.com).

```
var users = [{user: "Kamal"}, {user: "Vivek"}, {user: "Guna"}]
var idx = _.findIndex(users, {user: "Vivek"}); // returns 1
```

Now they used splice() to replace like this,

```
users.splice(idx, 1, {user: "Gowtham"})
```

but why not,

```
users[idx] = {user: "Gowtham"};
```

Now my question is, Is there any reason, not to do so or to use [splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) ?

Because it is so simple to use `array[index] = 'something';`. Isn't it ?

Comment: It is true that using `array[index]` is faster than `Array.splice()`: http://jsperf.com/array-index-vs-splice. But your mileage may vary depending on the size of the array, perhaps?

Comment: Unless you want to get the removed value (which isn't being done here), index assignment would make more sense and be most likely faster.

Comment: Ah, one difference is that `.splice()` will act more like `.push()` if `idx` is beyond the `.length` of the array, whereas index assignment would extend the array's length.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The only reasons they might do this are:

1. they want to also get the previous value
2. they want to 'cleverly' handle the case where idx == -1 by replacing the last element in the array, rather than putting it at -1, because splice will treat negative integers specially.  (this doesn't seem like it would fit the use-case you described)

in most cases, `arr[i] = "value";` will be better than `arr.splice(i, 1, "value");`