# How to update matched item with depth more of first?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

[This example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27641731/is-there-a-function-in-lodash-to-replace-matched-item/27641860) has a great reason how to update the object. But have one problem, this only works on objects at same level (depth).

How can I do something the same but with more of level one, depth?

I have an example object here :

```
let globalObj = [
    {
      fam_id: 1, // Random unique ID's.
      name: "No name",
      attributes: {
        "Key2": "*",
        "Key3": "*",
      },
      children: [
        {
          fam_id: 2, // Random unique ID's.
          name: "No name 2",
          attributes: {
            "Key2": "*",
            "Key3": "*",
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  ]
```

I have here object to update global, e.g :

```
let updateObj = {        
        fam_id: 2, // Mathed ID!
        name: "No name 3",
        attributes: {
            "Key2": "*",
            "Key3": "*",
         },
},
```

`findIndex` and `slice` methods works very well, but for depth 0? 
**How to filter more of depth 0? How about 1 or more?**

Thanks! o/

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by using a recursive function

```js
let globalObj = [
    {
      fam_id: 1, // Random unique ID's.
      name: "No name",
      attributes: {
        "Key2": "*",
        "Key3": "*",
      },
      children: [
        {
          fam_id: 2, // Random unique ID's.
          name: "No name 2",
          attributes: {
            "Key2": "*",
            "Key3": "*",
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  ];

let updateObj = {        
        fam_id: 2, // Mathed ID!
        name: "No name 3",
        attributes: {
            "Key2": "*",
            "Key3": "*",
         },
};

// recursive function
matchAndUpdate = (updater, target) => {
    if (updater.fam_id === target.fam_id) {
        target.name = updater.name;
        target.attributes = updater.attributes;
    }
    
    if ("children" in target && Array.isArray(target.children)) {
        target.children.forEach(child => {
            matchAndUpdate(updater, child);
        });
    }
}

globalObj.forEach(g => {matchAndUpdate(updateObj,g )});

document.getElementById('x').innerText = JSON.stringify(globalObj,null,"\t");
```

```css
pre {
  background-color: #456;
  color: #FED;
  font-size: small;
}
```

```html
<pre><code id="x"></code></pre>
```

Comment: Wow, nice. I'll test it :) Thank you for answering!

Comment: can you give me your email for contact, this works very well in VanillaJS, but in React returns undefined?

Comment: sure. Let's go into a chatroom, to leave this post uncluttered https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211894/tmp-question-id-61276800